# Factory Reset Ubuntu

Tags: reset

I want to reset Ubuntu. I have searched it on Google many times and I am new to Ubuntu so I am wondering how to reset it without too much complication. I have only Ubuntu on my PC i don't have windows 7/8/10 so i can't dual boot

I want to completely delete everything and have it start like it did when it was originally installed. Completely erase everything and restart, reinstall, and reconfigure Ubuntu.

Comment: You can always do a fresh install.

Answer (score 2):

Download Ubuntu. Create a bootable USB drive. Then start from it and it will ask you to start from live or install.

Click on install. When you get to the partition setup select to complete reinstall.

This will reformat your disk and reinstall everything like new.

Answer (score 1):

I know if your computer came with Ubuntu, then you might have an option to reset Ubuntu in the "Advanced options for Ubuntu xx.xx" menu. I have seen this in HP notebooks(apart from mine, which came with Windows 10(it's a HP 14-an009na(The brother to the 14-an013nr))and I do plan to put Ubuntu on it entirely)

Comment: Basically, use the reset option in grub