# X authority not found

Tags: xserver

[image: says broken]Help please new to Ubuntu I'm stuck on tty and don't know what to do here are photos of error [image: startx and this came up]

Comment: This appears to be a follow-up to [Ran test for ligthdm bug Says Xserver no path found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475777/ran-test-for-ligthdm-bug-says-xserver-no-path-found) - if you have a working internet connection you can try re-installing the X server core package (`sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core`). The non-existance of the .Xauthority file is normal if `temporaryuser` has not previously started an X session.

Comment: Try and said I had broken packages

Comment: Well, you will need to address that first. Depending on your level of expertise and patience, you might want to consider backing up your data and re-installing the system.

Comment: Ok I don't care about the data not much on harddrive how can I re-install

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Factory Reset Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859248/factory-reset-ubuntu)